# Conceptual difference between git fetch and git merge? Why do they feel same to me?

Tags: git

So `git fetch` conceptually means fetching something from remote branch. Now `git merge mybranch` means merging mybranch into current branch. I do not see what is the difference between the two? What is the stark conceptual "right in front of the eye" difference that I am missing?

Comment: Could you expand this question to explain *why* you're confused?  The two commands do two completely different things, and you outlined what they do in your question.  Without clarification, it's hard to know how to answer this in a way that you haven't already.

Comment: Actually I got confused & mistook the `git merge` for the `git push`. I was thinking along the lines of `git merge` merging my local changes into remote, which is wrong, of course. `git push` does that, not `git merge`. `git fetch + merge` is like a perforce `Get latest revision` and `git push` will do something like a perforce `Submit`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Git fetch doesn't modify your working copy

[git fetch](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html) will:

> Download objects and refs from another repository

It doesn't do anything to your working copy or any local branches - it *only* downloads new commits and updates remote branch references.

### Git merge modifies your working copy

[git merge](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html) will:

> Join two or more development histories together

I.e. merge  into the current branch history. It only operates in the current repository, it doesn't communicate with or modify a remote repository.

### Git pull: fetch *and* merge

Ordinarily you need to *fetch* commits from another repository and then *merge* (or rebase) them into your local branches.

[git pull](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html) is a related command. It will:

> Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch

I.e:

- download objects from a remote repository
- update remote branch references
- merge the remote branch into the local branch

in one command.

Comment: Suggestion - add a bit explaining that `pull = fetch+merge`. It may be outside the scope of the exact question, but if OP is confused about `fetch`/`merge`, there's likely to be some questions on `pull` too...

Comment: Your comment _it doesn't communicate with or modify a remote repository_ made me realize why I was getting confused. I was thinking `git merge` would affect the remote. Looks like it does not. `git push` does that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

git fetch is to get the changes without merging, giving you control. Git pull does a fetch and merge.

get fetch doesnt change your working data. git merge does. You can see the code changes before they happen with a git fetch

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are confused coming from another version control system like SVN? In SVN, the "fetching from remote" (= "svn update") gets the changes *and* "integrates" them.

In Git, these are two separate operations: `git fetch` only gets changes from the remote but does **not** "integrate" them. `git merge` then integrates these changes.